# alfresco /share redirects to a long site url?

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a weird problem with alfresco that when I access my `MY_HOSTNAME:8080/share` url it auto redirects to a long url appending current: `MY_HOSTNAME:8080/sharehttp://MY_IP:8080/share/page/site/documents/documentlibrary` which is inaccessible. If I login as other users it is fine. How to debug this problem?

Below is my `tomcat/webapps/share/site-index.jsp` file which I didn' t try to change.

```
<%@ page import="org.alfresco.web.site.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.site.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
   // retrieve user name from the session
   String userid = (String)session.getAttribute(SlingshotUserFactory.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_KEY_USER_ID);

   // test user dashboard page exists?
   RequestContext context = (RequestContext)request.getAttribute(RequestContext.ATTR_REQUEST_CONTEXT);
   if (!context.getObjectService().hasPage("user/" + userid + "/dashboard"))
   {
      // no user dashboard page found! create initial dashboard for this user...
      Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<String, String>();
      tokens.put("userid", userid);
      FrameworkUtil.getServiceRegistry().getPresetsManager().constructPreset("user-dashboard", tokens);
   }

   // redirect to site or user dashboard as appropriate
   String siteName = request.getParameter("site");
   if (siteName == null || siteName.length() == 0)
   {
      // Get and forward to user's home page
      SlingshotUserFactory slingshotUserFactory =
              (SlingshotUserFactory) FrameworkUtil.getServiceRegistry().getUserFactory();
      String userHomePage = slingshotUserFactory.getUserHomePage(context, userid);
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + userHomePage);
   }
   else
   {
      // forward to site specific dashboard page
      response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page/site/" + URLEncoder.encode(siteName) + "/dashboard");
   }
%>
```

I found some files that inside `alf_data/contentstore/DATE_TIME_DIRS/` that contains `"org.alfresco.share.user.homePage"` that points to the appended long url, which seems related. Don' t know how these are generated.

Comment: Are there any customisation in your Alfresco ? I mean behaviour which redirect to documentlibrary after authentication (like this thread https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/redirect-site-member-site-after-login) ? Can you provide the code ?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you on? Also - what user id are you using, and more importantly does it have any characters in it that are not alpha-numeric. I recall that we had an issue with login redirects on certain characters, but that it was subsequently fixed.

Comment: @Akah  I use 5.1 community version. I didn' t try to do any redirect customization. The problematic user id is admin, while other users are fine. Even the index url at the left top bar after login has been changed to that long nonsense. And after a system reboot and changed IP the appended url still have the old IP, which makes me wonder if there is any "cache" inside alfresco that might be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by cleaning up the tomcat cache with:

```
$ rm -rf tomcat/work/Catalina/*
```